# How to read julian date time format from an 8-byte value?

Tags: date, visual-c++, time

I have an eight-byte number describing "date time". I think it's a Julian-format date time. How can I convert it to a string in a readable form and the other way around?

I have tried "FILETIME" and "COleDateTime" structures but I am not getting the right value. Is there a special way to read Julian datetime?

Comment: "I think it's a Julian-format date time" any chance to find out exactly what it is?

Comment: dbase files uses julian Datetime format i read somewhere.

Comment: What's dbase ? What's `FILETIME` and `COleDateTime` ? Give some links. Give an example of what your number looks like.

Comment: http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/data_types.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the JulianCalender class?

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.juliancalendar(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.juliancalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This class is for MFC and supports Julian Calander

http://www.naughter.com/dtimeplus.html

Comment: thanks for your response . this date time really bugs me off.

Comment: "JulianCalender class"...it didnt help .

Comment: yes i used it . i used function "CGregorianCalendar ::GetDate(long val)" but i got wrong date .i wonder if i am putting right values of val.

Comment: date format is from foxpro dbf file.But i have to use it in my c++ code.